# React Google Maps module - How to handle GeoJSON MultiPolygons

Tags: google-maps, reactjs, geojson

So I've been using the google-maps-react [example for converting GeoJSON data to polygons](http://react-google-maps.tomchentw.com/#/geojson?_k=i0dr4p). The problem I've run into is that the example doesn't support converting GeoJSON features of the 'MultiPolygon' type. (Multiple polygons grouped together).

Is there anything I could change in the example to support that? Thinking I might be able to just add a case to the following function:

```
function geometryToComponentWithLatLng(geometry) {
  const typeFromThis = Array.isArray(geometry);
  const type = typeFromThis ? this.type : geometry.type;
  let coordinates = typeFromThis ? geometry : geometry.coordinates;

  switch (type) {
    case 'Polygon':
      return {
        ElementClass: Polygon,
        paths: coordinates.map(
          geometryToComponentWithLatLng, {
            type: 'LineString'
          }
        )[0],
      };
    case 'LineString':
      coordinates = coordinates.map(
        geometryToComponentWithLatLng, {
          type: 'Point'
        }
      );
      return typeFromThis ? coordinates : {
        ElementClass: Polyline,
        path: coordinates,
      };
    case 'Point':
      coordinates = {
        lat: coordinates[1],
        lng: coordinates[0]
      }
      return typeFromThis ? coordinates : {
        ElementClass: Marker,
        ChildElementClass: InfoWindow,
        position: coordinates,
      };
    default:
      throw new TypeError('Unknown geometry type: ${ type }');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Managed to fix this one myself by adding a case to the switch for 'MultiPolygon', and making some slight changes to the case for 'Polygon', like so:

```
switch (type) {
case 'MultiPolygon':
  return {
    ElementClass: Polygon,
    paths: coordinates.map(
      geometryToComponentWithLatLng, {
        type: 'Polygon'
      }
    ),
  };
case 'Polygon':
  coordinates = coordinates.map(
    geometryToComponentWithLatLng, {
      type: 'LineString'
    }
  )[0];
  return typeFromThis ? coordinates : {
    ElementClass: Polygon,
    path: coordinates,
  };
case 'LineString':
  coordinates = coordinates.map(
    geometryToComponentWithLatLng, {
      type: 'Point'
    }
  );
  return typeFromThis ? coordinates : {
    ElementClass: Polyline,
    path: coordinates,
  };
case 'Point':
  coordinates = {
    lat: coordinates[1],
    lng: coordinates[0]
  }
  return typeFromThis ? coordinates : {
    ElementClass: Marker,
    ChildElementClass: InfoWindow,
    position: coordinates,
  };
default:
  throw new TypeError('Unknown geometry type: ${ type }');
}
```